# Discord bot gives erorr: TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'am trying to make a discord bot but i ran into an error. This bot s wrote in python.

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

my_secret = os.environ['Token']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot `()` at `client = discord.Client`

```py
client = discord.Client()
```